# Are interfaces made useless by the template pattern?

Tags: c#, generics

Refer to the highest upvoted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802573/interfaces-whats-the-point) for why you should make an `IPizza` interface with a `IPizza.Prepare()` method.

This is highly upvoted, But I think the answer is flawed. Sure a pizza can be prepared, but so can literally anything. Interfaces are only a guarantee of behaviors, not a ***guarantee of type***, proven here:

```
    public interface IPizza
    {
        void Prepare();
    }
    public class Sandwich : IPizza
    {
        public void Prepare() { }
    }
```

If you expect to anywhere use a `Collection<IPizza>`, you have introduced a vulerability, maybe not security-wise but logic-wise. Because simply naming something `IPizza` is a guarantee of nothing (regarding type).

The above developer now must reintroduce type checking `if (IPizza is Pizza)` which per the highest upvoted comment, was a reason to use interfaces.

You might be tempted to add a return type to the `Prepare()` method, i.e. `IPizzaTopping Prepare()` but again, until you factor out the interface you can make anything be an `IPizzaTopping`. Once you factor out one interface, you might as well factor them all out in favor of hard types.

Here is the pizza example using the template pattern, all hard types:

```
    public class Pizza
    {
        private void Add(PizzaTopping topping) { }

        protected virtual PizzaTopping? Subclass_PrepareTopping(){ return null; } // Template pattern

        public void Prepare()
        {
            ThrowDough();  // private method
            SpreadSauce(); // private method
            SpreadCheese(); // private method

            if(Subclass_PrepareTopping() is PizzaTopping p){ Add(p); } // This might weaken my point by needing a type check, but it is really only a null check which is more a weakness of collections than a weakness of this example.

            Bake(); //private method
        }
    }

    public class PepperoniPizza : Pizza
    {
        protected sealed override PizzaTopping Subclass_PrepareTopping()
        {
            return new PepperoniTopping();
        }
    }
```

Now any public user of a `Pizza` can call the `Pizza.Prepare()` method and be guaranteed to get exactly the correct preparation.

If you say "Well I'll just inherit from PizzaTopping and return a gravy, and aha! I invalidated this whole discussion!"

...well the point of OOP is to create abstractions to the granular level. It's your job to make sure a `PizzaTopping` contains properties like `Collection<Cheese>`,`Collection<SlicedMeat>,` where, when the user desires to create a new `PizzaTopping`, they must compose the topping from your predefined granular types, which at the granular level are all hard sealed types.

Is this logic wrong in any way? Is there a pizza preparation example that throws a wrench in the above?

Comment: In the context of the Pizza example, I'd probably agree with you that the template method pattern is often going to be more useful than introducing interfaces. But in quite a lot of cases, interface-inheritance is much more useful than implementation-specialization, to the point that some languages don't have subclassing. The strategy pattern equivalent to your template method example would be something like `interface IToppingMaker { PizzaTopping MakeTopping() }; class Pizza { void Prepare(IToppingMaker t) { ... } }`

Comment: The point of an interface is that you do not need or want to care about the type that implements it. Creating code that does pointless things behind an poorly named interface is not exploiting an attack vector, it is just misunderstanding a concept and applying it inappropriately.

Comment: The core issue your question points out seems to be "if I name things inappropriately, then things aren't what they seem". Well, yes. The point is more that your IPizza interface states that "anything can be an IPizza as long as it has a `public void Prepare()` method". And then you created something that complies with that contract, but arbitrarily used a name that references other food. I fail to see how that is an issue other than one of nomenclature.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question: the fact that it is asked in a provocative way and written in an entertaining style is not sufficient to make it opinion based. There are plenty of objective arguments to make a difference between interfaces/protocols and generics/templates to demonstrate that in the general case the later is not equivalent to the former.

Comment: @Christophe: The opinionated basis of the question is not so much how the question is posed, but because it hinges on an arbitrary interpretation of a name. It would be a non-issue for Foo/Bar naming. It hinges solely on some contextual interpretation of what a name might mean; and the context derived from the names is then contradicted by OP who chose to implement `Sandwich : IPizza`, thus creating their own conflict.

Comment: @Flater Consider your web API exposes a `IMyAPI_Item` interface with a `void Construct()` method. If your API in any way _publicly_ accepts an instance of `IMyAPI_Item`, i.e. `MyAPI.Log(IMyAPI_Item item)` isn't it reasonable to assume an attacker can create a `Payload:IMyAPI_Item` and inside the `Payload.Construct()` method put a bunch of reflection and remote calls? You the dev thought "well, I will name this interface method `Construct` because thats what I need to happen, i need the item initialized" when in reality something else happens. This is what Sandwich:Pizza is meant to represent.

Comment: @Flater the fact that you prefer foo/bar is your right, but this doesn’t invalidate IPizza/ICar questions. If there is a confusion that is based on naming, this proves that there are objective arguments and this question adresses a real problem imho. I think that the 3 interesting and valid answers, all with objective arguments, suggest that it’s not opinion based.

Comment: @Christophe: It's not about preference, it's that it brings to light that this is not a technical issue but one of naming and setting your own expectations; which is highly subjective depending on a given context, and therefore prone to opinionated answers. OP chose for the class to implement the interface. If he thinks it's bad that this is the case; they should not have done so. There is nothing more to this.

Comment: @NWoodsman:  Who precisely is it that you are trying to defend your application from? Whoever is using your logger is doing so in their own runtime, where they get to call their own shots and suffer their own consequences. If this is your runtime, then you are also the source of the `Sandwich` class and the one who decided to have it implement the `IPizza` interface. If that is bad, then you should not have done it. If you cannot trust a developer on your own project to not inject malicious code, that is a very different fish to fry and design patterns are not the appropriate solution.

Comment: @NWoodsman _"well, I will name this interface method Construct because thats what I need to happen"_ The interface does not define the concrete implementation. An interface is not the arbiter of what is the right implementation, it is only the arbiter of what is a structurally compatible implementation. The developer of the class that implements the interface is the arbiter of what is the correct implementation of said interface. Every class is its own arbiter in this regards. This is the very purpose of what an interface is and should be used for.

Comment: @NWoodsman A web api also does not receive classes from its caller. A caller cannot inject a class into your codebase. It can only pass data, which your runtime instantiates into a class that your runtime knows. The only way to inject a new class here is either because your application blindly loads and executes third party DLLs (which is a problem of your own making) or by tampering with your application's DLLs, at which point anything is possible and interfaces are not a particular weak point compared to anything else.

Comment: One main use of interfaces is in tests and mocks; when you define TestPizza : IPizza. Or even better, using NSubstitute, Substitute.For<IPizza>(). Is a test pizza a pizza?

Answer (score 12):

I think there is a subtle distinction you're missing between guaranteeing *consistency* and guaranteeing *truth*.

When you write `public class Sandwich : IPizza` you are *telling* the compiler that a `Sandwich` is a type of `IPizza`. The compiler can then prove the *consistency* of code that passes a concrete `Sandwich` to something that is designed to work with *any* `IPizza`.

What the compiler *can't* do is verify the absolute *truth* of the English statement "a sandwich is a type of pizza". The step where real-world concepts are translated into types in the program is unavoidably *performed by a human*.

The purpose of defining the interface is that it leaves collaborating classes *open to extension* by providing them with new types of pizza. It defines a contract that those new types of pizza must follow. That contract doesn't tell you anything about whether the result will be *pleasant to eat*.

You might argue whether a [chocolate pizza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocolate_pizza) is a "real" pizza, but if your pizza-making machinery can handle one, then there is no problem declaring `class ChocolatePizza : IPizza`. However, trying to extend `ChocolatePizza` from a base `Pizza` class with default implementation is going to be a mess - it barely shares any of the same *implementation*, even though it can meet the same *interface*.

So, even though you didn't *plan* to support chocolate pizzas, your code was *open to extension* by someone else implementing that new class.

Answer (score 3):

From responses to previous answers I'm unsure if this is an honest question or argued in bad faith. Assuming the former:

No language construct can "protect" against developer intent (or incompetence). If someone writes code that compiles but makes no sense ala

```
public class Sandwich : IPizza
```

well, that's on the developer. One can write all sorts of stuff that confuses and befuddles in any language (especially {your least favorite language here}). This doesn't make the language constructs used obsolete. It might say something about the author however....

Comment: I demonstrated why the template pattern was better than the most upvoted answer on SO for "why use interfaces".  I argue that strong typing protects against silly interface implementations, which also represents slip-ups/bad logic in code. It also demonstrates why interfaces are attack vectors as opposed to strong typing.

Comment: Then it appears you've answered your own question. FWIW, an interface defines a contract as noted in a previous answer and is not a "guarantee of behaviors."

Comment: @NWoodsman "attack vectors" imply hostile intent. An interface is in no way a security barrier. If you want to shoot yourself in the foot, no language can stop you, it might, at best, make it more difficult. To protect against actual attacks you need other constructs, like processes or virtual machines. Besides, 'strong typing' is not well defined, and may be interpreted as 'whatever I think is good'.

Comment: @JonasH I was browsing Reference Source and came across this in `System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl` class: _"We use explicit polymorphism via internal methods for this. Another way would be to define an interface IGeneratedItemContainer with corresponding virtual "core" methods.  Base classes  would implement the interface and forward the work to subclasses via the "core" methods. While this is better from an OO point of view, and extends to 3rd-party elements used as containers, it exposes more public API. Management considers this undesirable, hence the following rather inelegant code."_

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces and generics are two very different, yet complementary things:

- An **interface** defines a behavioral **contract**. A class implementing `IPizza` must fulfill this contract, i. e. offer a `Prepare` method that meets the expectations. We don’t care if it’s a kind of pizza or not (for this we have classes). Btw, in real life projects, I never encountered any `IPizza`: naming of interfaces often describe a behavioral trait: `IPrintable`, `IDeliverable`, `ISortable`, `IComparable`. The problem with tutorial examples is that they are often obersimplified and thus misleading.
- **Generics** are using some kind of generalisation of a family of contracts or types
  to compose a more complex programming construct (e.g. class). Typically a collection of items that obey to dome sets of interfaces/types whose methods can be combined for making a more complex behavior. They do not substitute to interfaces. On contrary, they may use interfaces to define more complex containers.

By their essence, generics are compile-time type substitution, whereas interfaces offer a run-time polymorphism thanks to their defined contract.

Comment: Given the assertion **"the only thing an interface can offer is the expectation of finding a named property or method"**, how would you prove that "it's more than just a named property, its also a behavior" as you said? I don't see the behavioral aspect other than what's in the name. If the interface is expected to implement a property with a return type, that's somewhat better (if hard typed, i.e. the property isn't itself an interface instance).

Comment: I would also say that an `ICollection` is more of an `IPizza` than a `IComparable`, both of the former being abstractions of objects and not behaviors...

Comment: @NWoodsman I don‘t have to prove anything: that‘s the definition of an interface. Prove the contrary ;-) Thinking that it‘s just a set of names is a misunderstanding of the concept: you cannot just rely on the syntax of the language and ignore semantics and purposeof the language constructs

Comment: But you proved _my_ point by not having to prove anything =).  I guess I will keep on tagging my `Cars` with `IFlyable` ... hopes and dreams.

Comment: @NWoodsman fair point :-) But thinking about another fundamental difference between `IFlyable` and `Flyable<T>` the first is a  guarantee made  by the  contractor and that you can just consume at runtime, whereas the second is a guarantee/hope that is offered at compile time base on assumptions about T.  I’ve edited with an extra paragraph to make that point.

Comment: @NWoodsman The reason why interface definitions don't formalize contracts is because in most cases it wouldn't be feasible to do so. I have seen some attempts in more exotic programming languages to add pre-conditions and post-conditions to interface methods or to mandate things like implementations of certain methods must be side-effect free. But usually that's more work than it's worth and still doesn't cover everything you would expect to be part of the contract. So if you expect that any implementation of `IPrintable.print()` actually prints something, that must go into the documentation.